# Updating someone else's codebase from revision 49 to current

Tags: javascript, three.js

So I dealt with all the stuff that name errored, but there are still problems

Here's what the page should look like http://hamishtodd1.github.io/conferencing/glmol/minExample/nativeVersion/

And here's where I've gotten to
http://hamishtodd1.github.io/conferencing/glmol/minExample/

If you mousewheel a bit you can see some triangles glitched up stuff, so at least there's something, and I'm guessing I need to get onto turning face4's into two face3's. But I don't think that'll get this all the way, are there any general changes I definitely need to make because of revision differences?

Here's the file that matters the most, if it helps https://github.com/hamishtodd1/hamishtodd1.github.io/blob/master/conferencing/glmol/minExample/GLmol.js

Comment: `GLmol.js` is quite a file, almost 2k lines of code is a lot for someone to just casually go over. Face4 is definitely something that has been nuked from three.js, but it by no means the only thing.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration-Guide

There are a lot of updates across so many versions, maybe you can see the migration guide for three.js